# How to call SOAP service endpoint for RestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, soap

This is first time I am working with SOAP and spring together. But issue lots of issue. Not sure its valid question for not but its my requirement.

So I have on SOAP point which consume xml as input. This service is working fine. 
Now I am trying to call service method, something like below code.

```
HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/saop+xml");
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("soap/valid-req.xml");
        String xml = IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");

        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<>(xml, header);
        String response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/ws/HttpImport", entity, String.class);
```

is it possible to call SOAP service using spring Rest Template or do we have any other alternatives for that.

Could someone help on this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/  ? ... I have no clue about SOAP, but this looks a lot as what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
header.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML);
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("soap/valid-req.xml");
String xml = IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<>(xml, header);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/ws/HttpImport", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
String responseString =response.getBody();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.